# Save Email Attachment Over File From Outlook

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to use VBA to download the attachments in a specific outlook folder, save over a file on my hard drive (with that file's name) and then delete the email.

On the following line of code I'm receiving an error saying that the path does not exist. I'm copy and pasting the path so it should be correct.

```
atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
```

The entire code is below

```
Dim ns As Namespace
Dim inbox As MAPIFolder
Dim item As Object
Dim atmt As Attachment
Dim FileName As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim SubSubFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim VariableName As Name
Set ns = getnamespace("MAPI")
Set inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set SubFolder = inbox.Folders("Consulta Emails - Passivo
Set SubSubFolder = inbox.Folders("Consulta Emails - Lastro")

i = 0

If SubFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
MsgBox "Ainda não recebeu as planilhas necessárias"
Exit Sub
Else: End If
If SubFolder.Items.Count > 0 Then
For Each item In SubFolder.Items
For Each atmt In item.attachments
    FileName = "\dsapc429pfs.pactual.net\homefolder02$\wellsty\Desktop\Arthur Projects\Controle de Lastros\March tests\Consulta Passivo - Email.xls" 'muda path; vai salvar com o mesmo nome'
    atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
i = i + 1
item.Delete 'apagar os emails depois de baixar os anexos'
Next atmt
Next item
End If
```

Comment: All of the file names I've ever seen in that format start with two backslashes... \\  instead of \ maybe doublecheck to see if you copied the *entire* path?

Comment: Not quite sure how I messed that one up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify any local location. After saving the attachment to the disk you can move the saved file wherever you need.